# Is it possible to setup a WFS in Geoserver to serve XYZ endpoint?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, geoserver, tiling

I will like to know if it is possible to configure a GeoServer WFS to serve tiles in this format:

'http://{s}.host:port/geoserver/..../{z}/{x}/{y}.json'

**What I want to do is use "[Leaflet GeoJSON Tile Layer](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson/)" plug-in.**

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to setup a WFS in Geoserver to serve XYZ endpoint?

No, you would need to use a tool like [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/) to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to set TileStache.